# I have problem with import class from another (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, import

The problem is that I can not import class from another folder. Class that I want to import in LoginPage.py.

```
@ login.py


from selenium import webdriver

import time

import unittest

from Selenium.POMProjectDemo.Pages.LoginPage import LoginPage

class loginTest(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\python\Selenium\chrome_driver\chromedriver.exe')#, options = webdriver.ChromeOptions())
    #options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()


def test_01_login_valid(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://vk.com/')
    login = LoginPage(driver)
    login.enter_user_name()
    login.enter_user_password()
    login.login_button


@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.close()
    cls.driver.quit()
    print('test completed')


@Loginpage.py





from Selenium.POMProjectDemo.Locators.Locators import locators

from auth_data import vk_password,vk_login

from POMProjectDemo.Locators import Locators

class LoginPage():
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.index_email_id = locators.index_email_id
    self.index_pass_id = locators.index_pass_id
    self.loginButton_id = locators.loginButton_id

def enter_user_name(self):

    self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.loginField_id).clear()
    self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.loginField_id).send_keys(vk_login)

def enter_user_password(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.passwordField_id).clear()
    self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.passwordField_id).send_keys(vk_password)

def login_button(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.loginButton_id).click()
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium'
```

[image]

Comment: Use `pip install selenium`  or `sudo pip install selenium`  depending on your permissions to install Selenium first.

Comment: is `Selenium`(captalized) your own package name?

Comment: @Subtain Reza Selenium/pip installed. Al things are working, the problem is just with importing class.

Comment: @Lei Yang no, here is the path of LoginPage.py D:\python\Selenium\POMProjectDemo\Pages\LoginPage.py

Comment: try add this line at the top `sys.path.append(r'D:\python\')`

Comment: @Lei Yang Thank you very much. import sys
sys.path.append(r"D:\python/Selenium/POMProjectDemo/Pages") is working.

Comment: @Lei Yang Now, i have another problem, that:  
File "d:\python\Selenium\POMProjectDemo\Tests\login.py", line 28, in test_01_login_valid
   login = LoginPage(driver)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. 

Can it be related to the import or is it another problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way python figures out import paths is to first look at entries in sys.path and check if the module you are trying to import is accessible from any of the paths. It will stop at the first path under which your module is found.

e.g.

```
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/bhakta/dev/sonar/controller/venv/lib/python37.zip', '/home/bhakta/dev/sonar/controller/venv/lib/python3.7', '/home/bhakta/dev/sonar/controller/venv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/home/bhakta/dev/sonar/controller/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Let's say you have a module called "some_module" in /tmp

```
➜ ll /tmp/some_module
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bhakta bhakta 29 Jan 11 11:39 __init__.py

➜ cat /tmp/some_module/__init__.py
def foo():
   print("Hello")
```

```
➜ python
Python 3.7.10 (default, Oct 19 2021, 17:50:56)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/tmp")
>>> import some_module
>>>
>>>
>>> some_module.foo()
Hello
```

Now, lets say you have

```
➜ ll /var/tmp/some_module
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bhakta bhakta 45 Jan 11 11:43 __init__.py

➜ cat /var/tmp/some_module/__init__.py
def foo():
    print("From var/tmp Hello")
```

And you do:

```
➜ python
Python 3.7.10 (default, Oct 19 2021, 17:50:56)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/tmp")
>>> sys.path.append("/var/tmp")
>>>
>>>
>>> import some_module
>>>
>>>
>>> some_module.foo()
Hello
```

Notice that python found the first system path (/tmp) where some_module was found.

Thus:

```
➜ python
Python 3.7.10 (default, Oct 19 2021, 17:50:56)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/var/tmp")
>>> sys.path.append("/tmp")
>>> import some_module
>>>
>>> some_module.foo()
From var/tmp Hello
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explonation! i added import sys
sys.path.append(r"D:\python/Selenium/POMProjectDemo/Pages"). Now it is work

Comment: Now, i have another problem, that:  
File "d:\python\Selenium\POMProjectDemo\Tests\login.py", line 28, in test_01_login_valid
   login = LoginPage(driver)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. 

Can it be related to the import or is it another problem?